# Linux 7 Embedded Tomcat "server has a weak ephemeral diffie-hellman public key"

Tags: linux, security, ssl, centos, tomcat7

I have the "weak ephemeral diffie-hellman public key" error when connecting to my website. This problem is well documented but i can't seem to find an answer for my particular case.

my details are:

- RedHat 7
- Java Version 1.7.0_51
- OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 feb 2013
- **Embedded** tomcat 7

My website is a Java application that was installed and runs on the server using embedded tomcat.

This site has been hosted successfully on other servers (seemingly the same as this one).

But on this server i get the diffie-hellman when browsing to the site.

Now i know that to 'fix' this you simply need to update the server.xml file **BUT** i have no such file! and none of the other working server have this file.

I am a developer, but i did not make this application so i have no idea how it works.

The bottom line is how do i fix this problem when there is no server.xml and more over no tomcat folder in the /etc folder

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any "TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server-name.xml" files? These are read after the "server.xml" file, so you could add a fix to that file I believe.

Comment: I don't seem to have that folder. But i do have something close. i have user/local/[MyApp]/webapp/.extract/conf  but that folder is empty

Comment: What is in your /usr/share/tomcat{x}/conf and  /etc/tomcat{x} folder?

Comment: Or possibly /var/lib/tomcat{X}

Comment: I don't have any of the folders. tomcat is only on this server as part of the embedded website.